# If Cryptokitties could take so much computing power in Ethereum network, how can the network support dapps with scale?

Tags: dapps

There has been so much hype about developing dapps on Ethereum. However, even transactions of cryptokitties could clog the network, how could Ethereum network ever support some application like Whatsapp decentralized alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly true that cryptokitties clogged the network; The network was already near capacity, and cryptokitties was the straw that broke the camel's back.

However, there is currently very little room for the additional growth that will be needed if dapps are successful. The three main approaches are:

- Increasing the efficiency of software like Geth and Parity, and improving the hardware and network connections on which they are run, which will allow for increases in the gas limit, producing more capacity
- "Off-chain" systems that process transactions without talking to the main blockchain in the typical case; These include state channels and plasma.
- Sharding, which is currently under development, which will allow each validator to only validate a proportion of the blockchain, allowing for much greater capacity.